# Three.js - How to adjust a Light's glare effect?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want my Light (currently using `PointLight`) to have a larger `Glare` effect. Preferably casting on the large portion of the `Plane` rather than just a small location. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticed by adjusting the texture's `metalness` and `roughness` property, the glare effect's radius increased/decreased